# MySQL UNION returns ids that don't exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table **t** with 900 ids, 1-900. For the purpose of my task, I need to do something like (I think there is no meaning in try to reason behind this type of query, as it's something I'm experimenting on):
The id is NOT unique (as it is somewhat of foreign key let's say)!

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t5.id) FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) FROM t t1 WHERE {...} 
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT(t2.id) FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT(t0.id) FROM t t0 WHERE {...}) as t2 
         INNER JOIN t t3 ON t2.id=t3.id WHERE{...} 
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT(t3.id) FROM t t4 WHERE {...}) 
t5 ORDER BY t5.id
```

The *problem* is that the query, returns ids that are far from the 900 existing ones. The go all they way up to more than 10.000-20.000. Please help me provide you all the necessary information needed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you need to add `as id` in the second select field, like in the answer below.

Comment: You are right, the example I provided has a syntax error, gonna edit that. Although the problem is with the results, and not the syntax of this simplified example.

Comment: honestly, i think that you didn't translate your generalization of the problem correctly. you are using union, which cuts duplicates and also distinct... this means you could have at most 900 results. the first idea that comes to mind is that you didn't translate your example correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but perhaps you need to add `as id` in the second select field, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT(t1.id) **as id** FROM t t1 WHERE {...} UNION SELECT DISTINCT(t2.id) FROM t t2 WHERE {...} INNER JOIN t t3 ON t2.id=t3.id WHERE{...} UNION SELECT DISTINCT(t3.id) FROM t t4 WHERE {...}) t5 ORDER BY t5.id
```

Comment: and instead of `DISTINCT(id)` you need to add the subselects prefix `DISTINCT(t5.id)`. But altough you should be right, it would result in a different error message.

Comment: Thank you both guys. I edited the question, as it was something I missed just when I was typing here. The t5.id is as there already. As for the error, I'm greatly confused because it's the first time I notice something so strange. Of course it's a really weird query, but still, it makes no sense in my knowledge.